# GeoLite2 database region code

Tags: symfony, geoip, geolite2, geoip2

I have been asked to implement regions recognition from IP addresses with GeoIP that is already implemented (version 1 though, not version 2) for my company's website. It is developped with symfony, and i'm quite new to the framework, but also to everything web-related. So I figured out I would twist the calls to geoIP in the existant code to try and get the regions codes. After reading the doc, I finally got to "geoip_region_by_name" to which I am supposed to give the IP Address of the user. So far so good. But when I tried using that, I got a "Service not available" error.

I figured I was probably doing something wrong. I went through a lot of documentation, and I got to the point where I realized it might just be that the regions are not included in the free version whatsoever. I thought this information would be easy to find, but it actually wasn't at all, and I'm kind of stuck.

Thanks for the help